# How can I launch a vanilla non-marketplace open CentOS ami on Amazon EC2?

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

A while ago I [did some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555953/ec2-ami-for-centos-5-x-64-bit/17974762#17974762) and launched a Centos 6.4 image from the Amazon Marketplace. It didn't have any fees (other than usage fees).

That was working fine until I messed up a config file and the instance would no longer boot. Well it turns out [there is a gotcha](https://serverfault.com/questions/522173/aws-vol-xxxxxxx-with-marketplace-codes-may-not-be-attached-as-as-secondary-dev) that prevents you from unattaching amazon volumes that were created from the marketplace and reattaching them as secondary volumes on other instances.

The error message says:

> Client.OperationNotPermitted: 'vol-xxxxxxxx' with Marketplace codes may not be attached as a secondary device.

Well the [answer on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Amazon-EC2/Is-it-possible-to-rescue-an-EBS-volume-which-has-marketplace-codes) said something like:

> My name is Julien Ellie, I'm one of the engineers on the AWS Marketplace team at Amazon. We are aware of this issue and we're looking into what can be done to address it. In the meantime if you contact customer support, they can help you through this and hopefully get you unblocked. You can reach them at 1-800-407-2983 or you can find the contact us form on the marketplace website  at the bottom of the page.

So I called that number and amazon was on it - they are in fact helping me out - something about removing the code and rescuing the data to another volume. Only problem is that this is taking a few hours.

Well - I still want to run Centos 6.4 but if I have an issue again I don't want the volume to have the marketplace code on it - so how can I launch an "open"  AMI of `Centos 6.4` ?

[The CentOS page](http://wiki.centos.org/Cloud/AWS) says:

> Using the AMI's directly is currently deprecated. We are working to resolve issues and establish automation as well as monitoring around resources and process that will allow us to re-enable direct AMI instantiation. In the mean time, the AMI's are listed at the bottom of this document for legacy / reference purposes.

That's fine but is there another solution to get a vanilla version of CentOS 6.4 other than

1. "use this AMI that Bubba made and put on his blog"
2. Build your own CentOS AMI from scratch (not totally against this one just sounds complicated)

What are the options here?

Comment: I seem to be pimping packer today! install centOs on a box as vanilla as you like then...
http://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html enjoy ;)

Comment: in case anyone else is looking - so far this look like the most promising - http://www.bashton.com/blog/2012/how-to-make-your-own-centos-6-amis/

Comment: not complicated to build from scratch. See: http://www.michael--martinez.com/amazonaws/

Comment: I created instances which based on the official CentOS6.x AMIs from AWS Marketplace, then I tried all the answers above but still failed. But finally I made it by following these two articles: https://www.caseylabs.com/remove-the-aws-marketplace-code-from-a-centos-ami/ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage_expand_partition.html